# Azure Front Door for SPA Application (React) showing 404 on specific path

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-storage-account, azure-static-web-app, azure-front-door

I have created an azure front door, and in that created an endpoint, in endpoint , created three different front end routes, one for api , one for portal and one for checkin-widget.
then created three different origins for backends.
the api route is `/api/*`
the checkin route is `/checkin/*`
and for portal is `/portal/*`
api and checkin are working fine
but portal is throwing error of 404.
the portal and widget is in storage account static app and api is on app service.
when I hit `someafd-uniquename.z01.azurefd.net/portal/`
it send 200 response message for for portal in network but for assets like `/static/js/main.235cbe7f.js` and
`/static/css/main.c87164bd.css` throwing 404.
because for js and css assets, it is using base url like
`someafd-uniquename.z01.azurefd.net/static/js/main.235cbe7f.js`
but it should send req to
`someafd-uniquename.z01.azurefd.net/portal/static/css/main.c87164bd.css`
because checkin widget is doing the same sending reqest with prepending checkin/ in URL.

I have checked every known possibility.
I have also defined a ruleset as in below Image.
[[image: Rules set for URL Rewrite. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW5T0.png)]
[image: This is the endpoint list, and each endpoint have own origin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully configured routing rules for http://mycustomsite.com using Azure Front Door. Here's a breakdown:

> **Routing Configuration:**

- Requests to /portal are directed to the Azure Front Door resource for
  the portal.
- Requests to check in are routed to the Azure Front Door resource for
  check-in.
- Requests to /api are directed to the Azure Front Door resource for
  the API.
- Requests to the root URL, /, are routed to an external destination.

> **Permanent Redirect Rules:**

I've implemented a ruleset for permanent redirects based on the request path:

- If the request path contains /portal, the origin group is overridden
  to serve the portal static web app.
- If the request path contains /checkin, the origin group is overridden for the
  checkin static web app.
- If the request path contains /api, the origin group is overridden to serve
  the API app service.
- If the request path is base path, It will be a permanent redirect to external destination host, [www.mycustomsite.com](http://www.mycustomsite.com)

This setup ensures that specific paths are appropriately directed to their respective resources, and I've added permanent redirect rules for external destinations based on specific conditions. **If there are any specific details or further clarifications needed, feel free to ask.**

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the rule sets? I can't figure out rule conditions and actions required.

Comment: I have added the rule set screenshot above.

Answer (score 1):

- Change the SPA routing in [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website) Static Web [app](https://dev.to/gkarwchan/routing-in-spa-and-how-to-handle-it-with-azure-static-web-app-38kc) and deploy the app again.

```js
{
    "navigationFallback": {
      "rewrite": "index.html",
      "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif,ico}", "/*.{css,scss,js}"]
    }
}
```

- Code reference [from](https://johanrin.com/posts/deploy-react-app-in-azure-storage-and-static-web-apps/) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77549485/how-to-deploy-a-create-react-app-project-to-azure/77551767#77551767).

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <center>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </center>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Deployment status in Git Action:**
[image]

**Static Web app Output:**

[image]

**Cofigure the Azure Front Door :**
[image]

[image]

[image]

- For more details refer to hosting a React JS single page application on Azure Blob Storage & Azure CDN for SSL, HTTP to HTTPS redirect and rewrite client routing [traffic](https://antbutcher.medium.com/hosting-a-react-js-app-on-azure-blob-storage-azure-cdn-for-ssl-and-routing-8fdf4a48feeb).

Comment: I have tried this under a file routes.json on root level, But It did not worked.
I have also tried below code

`{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ],
  "platformErrorOverrides": [
    {
      "errorType": 404,
      "serve": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
}`

It also did not work for me properly.
Only my provided answer worked, the rulesSet.

Comment: I'm not sure why my solution not worked, and I'm not sure at what point you or I missed. It's good that you found a solution in Azure Front Door with the ruleset.