# Azure static web app anonymous health check route

Tags: health-monitoring, health-check, azure-static-web-app

I have an Azure static web app with the staticwebapp.config.json like so:

```json
"routes": [
  {
    "route": "/*",
    "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
  }
]
"navigationFallback": {
  "rewrite": "index.html",
  "exclude": ["/static/media/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}", "/static/css/*"]
}
```

This works and all routes need to go through auth. Now, I want to add an exception to the `/health` route to allow for health check services to see if my site is up and running. How can I do this? I tried adding a route like this:

```json
"routes": [
  {
    "route": "/health",
    "allowedRoles": ["anonymous"]
  },
  {
    "route": "/*",
    "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
  }
]
"navigationFallback": {
  "rewrite": "index.html",
  "exclude": ["/static/media/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}", "/static/css/*"]
}
```

But that does not work, `/health` route still requires authentication.

Comment: please share the code

Comment: That _is_ the code, Azure static web apps have a config file that is used to determine the authentication and access to routes. You can see the docs here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration but in classic MS style, they either do not provide for a solution for my problem or their documentation is sorely lacking.

Comment: which language you are looking for like react etc

Comment: It's a react site, yes

Comment: What type of authentication you are looking for . You asked for health check? /health will work when we have code like / . Here is the example of [routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77549485/how-to-deploy-a-create-react-app-project-to-azure/77551767#77551767).

Comment: Thanks, I get that part. In the code you linked, there are individual routes for anonymous and authenticated. What I have above is the catch-all `/*` and then I want to add an exception for the `/health` route. That does not work.

Comment: shell i give with user and password as login

Answer (score 0):

What do you have behind the `/health` ?

It may be the `navigationFallback` that is redirecting you to index.html which requires authentication.

> You can define a fallback rule by adding a navigationFallback section. The following example returns /index.html for all static file requests that **don't match a deployed file**. [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#fallback-routes)

To be sure, add `/health` to the excluded path:

```
"exclude": ["/static/media/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}", "/static/css/*", "/health"]
```

It is not due to the [order of routes in your config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#routes)

> Rule evaluation stops at the first match

Comment: Tried this as well but the health route does not work

Answer (score 0):

From the example given here, [Configure SWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#example-configuration-file),  this most closely matches your requirement..

{
"route": "/calendar*",
"rewrite": "/calendar.html"
}

so you may need the wildcard at the end as indicated by

> Wildcard pattern

...

> The calendar.html file can then use client-side routing to serve a different view for URL variations like /calendar/january/1, /calendar/2020, and /calendar/overview.

> Note

> A route pattern of /calendar/* matches all requests under the /calendar/ path. However, it won't match requests for the paths /calendar or /calendar.html. Use /calendar* to match all requests that begin with /calendar.

Comment: I was really hoping this was the answer but I tried and it does not work